# Cross referencing apple financial report with in-app apple receipt

Tags: ios, in-app-billing

Is there any common field inside of the generated financial report from iTunes connect you can cross reference with the validated in-app receipt you may have stored in your database? For example, the receipts have a  transaction ID, but that does not exist in the financial report, so it can't be used to cross reference a record.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not. Apple support wrote me that "a detailed purchase and subscription report with transaction IDs or timestamps currently does not exist within our Sales and Trends reports" . Otherwise it would affect users privacy.

There is randomly generated Subscriber ID in subscriber report (https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/itcf20f3392e) that is unique to each customer and developer, but it is not connected with receipt information. 
If subscription volume is small, those reports may help, especially Subscriber event .

I believed that applicationusername can be set and used as Subscriber id, but it can not, it is used only for fraud detection on the Apple side.